# Show different content on the same Activity

Tags: android, json, android-activity

In my database I have the following table:

```
|----------- Product -----------|
| id | name | description | qtd |
| 1  | A    | Product A   |     |
| 2  | BB   | Product B   |     |
| 3  | CCC  | Product C   |     |
| 4  | DDDD | Product D   |     |
```

I wanted the "Ativade" show beyond information, 1 input and 1 button.

```
|-------------|
|      A      |
|  Product A  |
|      ____   |
| Qtd |____|  |
|             |
|  | NEXT |   |
|             |
|-------------|
```

After the user enters the amount, and click "Next". Was going to appear the product B:

```
|-------------|
|      BB     |
|  Product B  |
|      ____   |
| Qtd |____|  |
|             |
|  | NEXT |   |
|             |
|-------------|
```

And after the last product, the input data would be updated in the field "Qtd" in the table "Product".

How can I do this, given that the number of products is not always the same, and that this information comes from an external database rather than SQLite?

Comment: show wat u done so far.

Comment: Isn't it enough to loop through your ids and get your qtd int for each id, save them in the end? What is the problem? "number of products is not always the same"... can you show what you mean?

Comment: I still do not have anything done! What wanted to know is how do I show the same "Activity", different content. A similar example. How would a quiz? In which the "activity" would have one input to answer, and one button to move to the next question. And as I know not how many issues are ... I can not create an "activity" for each question.

Comment: Like a viewPager? http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have fetched everything you need from the database.

One way of doing this could be:

- You start by storing all the data in an Array of Map's

  `ArrayList< Map< String, String >> list;`

So you now have something like this:

`list[x] = {"name" => NAME_x, "description" => DESCRIPTION_x, "qtd" => QTD_x}
...`

- You declare an instance variable `private int position = 0;`
- You create a layout (L)
- You then create your Activity and use (L) layout
- Add a method (M) that will set the correct data from `list[position]` into the layout's views
- Add an OnClickListener on the button `(next)`. Each time the button is pressed to get the value from the `EditText` field and assign it to `list[position]["qtd"]`. Then you increment `position` and call (M) method. (Don't forget to check if you have reached the end of your ArrayList before calling (M), and then do whatever you want with the data you got).

Hope this helps